# Pentaho Kettle, Can't set Field defaults in Text File Input

Tags: csv, null, default, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I am importing a CSV file to be processed in a transformation. Originally I was using the CSV File Input. I later learned I could not have any null values. So I switched to the Text File Input because it had a Default Column in the Fields Tab that was supposed to set a "Default value in case the field in the text file was not specified (empty)"

[image]

However, when I populate the Default column for a Field with a Null value. The field remains **null** in the Transformation. Any idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is the value `null` literally in the CSV? I think is evaluated as `"null"` like the text string. So you need to replace it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Tested on version 5.4

The `Default` option under `Fields` tab works as expected, so there must be something else you're doing wrong. Hopefully this will lead you in the right direction. Remember please that string literal value "null" is not a `NULL` value. If this is your case consider replacing those values in second step.

Input file with header column and `;` as delimiter:

[image]

Here is the results with correctly replaced null values from input file with the specified default value:

[image: Results]

And the settings are:

[image: Settings of text file input]

### Edit

After comment that in version 6.0.1 it is not working for the OP, I'm attaching an image with a different way to approach this problem.

Use `If field value is null` step to give default values for nulls.

[image: If field value is null approach]

Comment: Wow, I followed your steps exactly and got <null> instead of "default"

Comment: Could version have something to do with it I'm using 6.0.1

Comment: I don't remember this exactly, but for some reason I didn't switch to version 6 and stick with version 5.4 instead. There was some issue I stumbled upon and while it was working on 5.4 on 6 it was not.

Comment: There is another way to achieve your goal, see my edited answer.

Comment: Works like a charm, Thanks